# WebAPI passed post parameters is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm testing with WebAPI 2 and I have created the following controller method.

```
// POST api/values
public string Post([FromBody] string value)
{
    string returnValue = "Return: " + value ;
    return returnValue;
}
```

When i'm posting the following message with fiddler the method parameter keep returning null.

```
POST http://localhost:50814/api/Values/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50814
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 14

{value: "New"}
```

I have simplyfied my code already as much as i can but still it stays null.

I think I'm overlooking something very simple but i'm out of ideas. Could someone please help me?

Thanks Sander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're taking a simple String from your Controller's Post method, try sending just this:

```
POST http://localhost:50814/api/Values/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50814
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 10

"MyString"
```

Comment: You're welcome. In order to work with the request you made, you could add a dummy object like `public class MyDummy
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}` and change your method header to `public string Post([FromBody] MyDummy myDummy)`.

Comment: I've run into this issue as well. I'll try this solution tonight. 

But I'm trying to understand why this is a problem? Is this a binding issue somehow? If the method parameter is called 'value' and the decoration specifically calls out that it comes from the message body, why can't it read it?