# Post json as string to server using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to send a JSON as string (not as object) to the server (in this case it's a WebAPI). I always get a error code 500.

I succeeded to get response from the server when the request was GET and without sending data to the server. this achieved by JsonObjectRequest.

Now, I trying to send a POST request with JSON as string. For that I try

- JsonObjectRequest
- StringRequest
- GsonRequest
- JsonRequest - here I supplied my json in the requestBody

Before using volley, I used other methods to send request to server which require to simply build an object, serialized to json (string) and pass via StringEntity.

I can't understand where should I pass the json in the request. or what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't exactly understand why do you want to send the JSON as a string and not as an object. Nevertheless, in your WebAPI endpoint you should put a breakpoint in the Post method of the ApiController and see whether the request gets there or not.

Probably, you're mixing the content-types of the request. If you want to send a simple string request from Volley, you should just use the `StringRequest` and send there the JSON text. Thus, in the WebAPI POST method you must get the string without being deserialized to JSON. I answered once a similar question of how this string request should be made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21840549/812598).

However, as I said before I would suggest using always JSON requests which includes the `contentType:"application/json"` header, and receive requests in the WebAPI deserialized.

Comment: Problem solved! thank you :) my problem was with the headers. Once I delete the headers and used a JsonObjectRequest it works!! @GoRos

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> url = "yoururl"; StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
> new Response.Listener<String>() 
> {
>     @Override
>     public void onResponse(String response) {
>         // response
>         Log.d("Response", response);
>     }
> }, 
> new Response.ErrorListener() 
> {
>      @Override
>      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
>          // error
>          Log.d("Error.Response", response);
>    }
> } ) {     
> @Override
> protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
> {  
>         Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
>         params.put("your_field", youJSONObject.toString());  
>
>         return params;  
> } }; queue.add(postRequest);
> ```

Try in this way to make the post (it should work with json obj or array)

Comment: It's working now, but in this method I need to add every single field of the object and not the whole object . can I send the serialized json instead of every field ? thanks for your answer @iwen

Comment: What do u mean for whole objcet? In this way you should be able to send a JsonArray too (so you can send a complex object like jsonobj with jsonarray) ... Can you be more precise?

Comment: Problem solved. my problem was with the headers. thanks anyway @iwen